# What is a proper way to pass a parameter to Set-Alias in powershell?

Tags: powershell, alias, dotfiles

A little background:

I use PowerShell on windows xp at work and I set a bunch of useful shortcuts in `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` in `My Documents`, trying to emulate Mac environment
inspired by [Ryan Bates's shortcuts](http://github.com/ryanb/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/aliases)

I have things like:

```
Set-Alias rsc Rails-Console
function Rails-Console {Invoke-Expression "ruby script/console"}
```

Which works just fine when in command prompt I say:

```
rsc #it calls the proper command
```

However this doesn't work properly

```
Set-Alias rsg Rails-Generate
function Rails-Generate {Invoke-Expression "ruby script/generate"}
```

So when I do :

```
rsg model User
```

which is supposed to call

```
ruby script/generate model User
```

all it calls is

```
ruby script/generate  #Dumping  my params
```

So how would I properly modify my functions  to take params I send to functions?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function doesn't take any arguments so it's not terribly surprising that none get passed.

You should write it like so:

```
function Rails-Generate { ruby script/generate $args }
```

Note that `Invoke-Expression` is unnecessary here. PowerShell is a *shell*—it has no problem calling other programs directly.

Demo:

```
PS Home:\> Set-Alias foo Call-Foo
PS Home:\> function Call-Foo { args }
PS Home:\> foo bar baz
argv[0] = Somewhere\args.exe

PS Home:\> function Call-Foo { args $args }
PS Home:\> foo bar baz
argv[0] = Somewhere\args.exe
argv[1] = bar
argv[2] = baz
```

Comment: Johannes - Thank you ! I'm new to powershell - so I wasn't sure how to pass args, it doesn't work the same as bash..

Thank you!

Comment: He would have to consider Invoke-Expression or other means to avoid arguments that use some special characters. Things like : or -- can start to mess up powershell parsing your full commandline.